# Mongose как правильно организовать схему отправки данных?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

У меня **есть 2 коллекции данных. PRODUCT и ORDERS.**
И **они на прямую зависят друг от друга, по бизнес логике.** **PRODUCT это то что бизнес выкладывает в список товаров**. А **Orders это список заказов. То есть заказы, берутся из PRODUCT.** **Когда я пытаюсь отослать заказ одним запросом**. Где повторяются две json строки. То mongoose. Скидывает лишь то что ниже. Это я выделил красной линией.

*ВОПРОС:* Как мне организовать схему заказов так. Что бы я одним заказом. Мог прислать на сервер любое количество продуктов?

-При этом я **не могу**

**Знать сколько продуктов в конечном счете будет у бизнеса.**

*Возможные решения которые я придумал...*

> На front end класть все в массив. И от туда доставать все товары.
>   Перебирая каждый, и отсылая. (костыльно)
>
> К каждому заказу нарисовать огромную кнопку. Через которую будет
>   осуществляться заказ.(костыльно)

```js
const Order = require('../../models/order.js')

exports.createOrder = (req, res) => {
    const order = new Order(req.body)
    order.save().then(result =>{
        res.status(200).json({
            post: result
        })
    })
}
```

[image: схема]

Comment: А что, значит "Mongoose сбрасывает"?

Comment: Нужен пример отправляемых данных и фрагмент кода, который записывает их в базу

Comment: @Дмытрык просто отправляет только нижнюю часть запроса. А на верхнюю идет ошибка.

Comment: @NikitaUmnov добавил код

Comment: а как вы определяете, что именно нижняя отправляется, а не наоборот? Какую ошибку показывает?

Comment: @Дмытрык я создал несколько документов с параметром body. И дал им разные имена. Ошибку могу скинуть чуть позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подразумеваю, что в `req.body` находится массив документов. Если не так - то должно быть так. В таком случае, можно просто сохранять все элементы массива в цикле.
В `req.body` подразумеваются данные вида:

```
{items: [
    {body: "books", quality: 40},
    {body: "pens", quality: 180},
    ...
]}
```

Пример получения и записи данных в базу:

```
const Order = require('../../models/order.js')

exports.createOrder = (req, res) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let item of req.body.items) {
        const order = new Order(item);
        promises.push(order.save())
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(result =>{
        res.status(200).json({
            post: result
        })
    })
}
```

В данном примере используется `Promise` для ожидания завершения всех вставок